# How can i connect two files on a mac?

Tags: php, macos, emacs, mamp

I just bought my first mac and I develop in PHP. I run MAMP to serve my php files. You have to save files to Applications/MAMP/htdocs to be able to serve a file. I would rather have one file in the root directory that sends all the files I create to htdocs so that I can access them easier in emacs and such from the command line. How could I do this?

Comment: ? you want a symlink or just another web directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `httpd.conf` of MAMP. You can change the `root folder` of you `WWW` there. Look for the `http.conf` file in the Apache directory, and then look for `htdocs` and change that path.